# Problem in removing songs only from playlist, not delete the song file!

Tags: delete, music, music-player, audacious

I am using Audacious 3.9 as my default music player on my Fedora Gnome 27 and I'd like to remove a song of my current playlist, but the matter is: there is no choice for that neither in right-click menu on songs nor any delete icon, etc. I also searched for that but the result was enabling a plugin that remove song files! Now please let me know if it is possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to remove the song from your playlist using `audtool` from the command line?  `man audtool` for usage.

Comment: Yes, I am able to remove an added song from current playlist; e.g. First I find the position of song with `audtool --playlist-position` which gives me a number that shows the place (position) of that song in active playlist then I am able to just remove that song from playlist via `audtool --playlist-delete [POSITION]`. So how can I remove songs from playlist in audacious application graphically? (_Also I'm sorry for late respond!_) @TimothyMartin

Comment: Are you able to highlight the song to be removed by clicking on it and then hit the `Delete` key to remove it?

Comment: Oh! i didn't know that! Yes, I test it and it just works (it removes the song from playlist). @TimothyMartin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to highlight the song in your playlist by clicking on it and then remove it by clicking the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. Now is there any option or plugin to do it on right-click menu? - I should take a look at it!